# A values list into result set without UNION ALL

Tags: mysql

I found how to make a result set from a list of values without using temporary tables:

```
select 12 as id
union all
select 155 as id
union all
select 139 as id
union all
select 11 as id
```

this result set can be used in various joins later.

Now I am seeking for a possibility to shorten the SQL string passed to MySQL. Ideally there could be something like:

```
select (12, 155, 139, 11) as id;
```

but there is no such syntax in MySQL. Any thoughts?

Comment: While everyone is thinking, I am really interested in your thoughs as to why you need the SQL shorter. Is it for readability issues(too much union?). Do you use any language to generate the string (php?java?shell script?). Also sharing a few real sample sql might help as there might be ways to shorten your sql in your where clause/join e.t.c.

Comment: @Jacky Cheng: I am usin PHP to form the string. The problem is that the list could contain hundreds and possibly thousands of elements.

Comment: You are probably looking for something like `select * from values (12),(155),(133),(11)` but MySQL does not support that. The `union` is your only option.

Comment: It'd be great if you could show related code (php+mysql) as i think there isn't a way to shorten SQL as you described in your question. However there are many possible ways outside of your question's scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called the "table value constructor" in the SQL standard, and it would work like this:

```
SELECT id FROM (VALUES (12), (155), (139), (11)) AS t(id)
```

Unfortunately, it is not available in MySQL. To my knowledge, at least these databases support it:

- CUBRID
- DB2
- Derby
- HSQLDB
- PostgreSQL
- SQL Server
- Sybase ASE

And at least these databases don't and need to emulate it using `UNION ALL`:

- MS Access
- Firebird
- Informix
- Ingres
- MariaDB
- MySQL
- Oracle
- SQLite
- Sybase SQL Anywhere

#### Workaround using IN predicate

If this is merely about syntax (not performance), you could of course also query a table that is known to contain *at least* the values that you're looking for, and then simply use an `IN` predicate to list the values:

```
SELECT id FROM some_table WHERE id IN (12, 155, 139, 11)
```

Of course, this will probably be quite slower than the `UNION ALL` solution.

But syntactically, this is an obvious workaround given the fact according to the SQL standard, the `IN` predicate's "in value list" is really just syntax sugar for a "table value constructor" (although, I don't believe any SQL engine really implements that alternative syntax):

```
8.4 <in predicate>

2) Let IVL be an <in value list>.

   ( IVL )

   is equivalent to the <table value constructor>:

   ( VALUES IVL )
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but you can generate a list-as-string from a list of values with the group_concat function:

```
select group_concat(x.id ', ') as idList from 
(
select 12 as id
union all
select 155 as id
union all
select 139 as id
union all
select 11 as id
) x
```

**UPDATE**: if you're actually looking to do the opposite i.e. pass over a comma-delimited list (e.g. `select '12, 155, 139, 11' as id` for use in the database, then you'll need a SPLIT function: this does not yet exist in mysql, but you can find several examples online: here for instance:

http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/199134

Comment: nono haha, you didn't get what OP wants. OP wants to shorten the QUERY SQL itself, as in he want to do the same thing with  a 40 letters SQL instead of a 200 letters SQL full of UNION. it is purely base on readability, he wants his code to be shorter.

Comment: why don't you answer the question, then?

Comment: i apologize if i come off rude, no need to be spiteful. my reply to you question would be because it is impossible within the amount of info given by OP, we are all waiting for OP to actually update his question, then we'll help. @LukasEder gave an answer which is "possible" but I see no benefit in his answer as well. OP has some sort of SQL he's not showing and his answer will mostly not achieve the goal of shortening the real SQL.

Comment: @JackyCheng: My answer is beneficial to the question as it is right now: *"No, what you want to do isn't possible right now"*. If things stay the way they are right now, future visitors will profit from finding this question and my answer.

Comment: @LukasEder that's exactly why I didn't vote your answer down nor critic it. Your answer is very informative and "answered" the question, but it doesn't "help OP solve his fundement problem", where as davek is flatout wrong.